Does the word 'single' in this sentence need an article?
My friend wrote:
"Why? Because Russia has always been a bit of a paradox to the most of the world: nobody knows much about it, never been there or knows single Russian person."
I told her I think it should be "a single Russian person." Which is correct?

Yes. You have also have an extra "the": "Paradox to [the] most of the world: nobody knows much about it, has ever been there, or knows a single Russian person."

Thanks @YosefBaskin, didn't even catch the 'the'.

It wouldn’t surprise me to learn that the friend who wrote that is a Slav. It’s quite common for native speakers of Slavic languages to fail to use articles where English requires them (because their languages don’t have articles).

The final element never been there or knows single Russian person lacks a subject. People talk like that (disjointed phrases and fragments not syntactically connected), but that's not the kind of utterance you should be learning from. It's just "word salad".

Yes. Single is an ordinary adjective, not a determiner like some or both.

The correct form:
“Because Russia has always been a bit of a paradox to most of the world: nobody knows much about it, has ever been there, or knows a single Russian person.”
(That is grammatically correct.  I would question whether “paradox” is the right word to use.  Perhaps “puzzle” or “mystery” would be be better.  Plus, do most people know zero Russians?)

You could also use enigma. "A riddle wrapped in a mystery inside an enigma" -- Churchill describing the Soviet Union.

In Soviet Russia, article precedes you!

It is a general rule of English that noun phrases with singular countable nouns require a Determiner (a word like a, the, this, that, every, each, some, one, two, no, any, my, Bob's and so on).

*I need pen. (ungrammatical)
I need a/the/this/that pen. (grammatical)

The word pen is countable, and in (1) above we see that when singular pen appears on its own with no Determiner, it's ungrammatical.
In the Original Poster's example, the noun person is both countable and singular. It therefore requires a Determiner:

*single Russian person (ungrammatical as a whole noun phrase)

a single Russian person (grammatical)


OP is correct, here.
